# On topology over R[x]

Tags: general-topology, polynomials, topological-rings

Take $R$ a topological ring. Suppose for example that $R$ is equipped with the $I$-adic topology for a certain ideal $I$. Take $R[x]$ the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $R$ and variable $x$. I was looking for a natural topology on $R[x]$ induced by the topology on $R$. I was thinking for example to take the set $$ R[x]I^n$$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ as fundamental system of neighborhood of the origin. The idea is take the ideal generated by $I^n$. Is it right? If yes, is this natural? If not, is there another one?

Comment: Something natural seems like to define it to make the evaluation map continuous. And also the evaluation maps of the derivatives : all the maps $P\mapsto P^{(k)}(x) $ are continuous. Thus, taking the coarsest topology satisfying that seems like a plan I think.